# how to put front and backslash as a string in java?

Tags: java

the output should be like this...

```
    *
  / | \
 *  *  *
/   |   \
```

...and so on. I'm having a problem is putting the slashes. I tried terminal.putCharacter('/'); but never worked. Anyone can help me? I'm new at this.

Comment: could you show us what you have tried till now ?

Comment: use `\ ` as escape character for every \

Answer (score 2):

Make sure for every '\' character, put a '\' character in front of it (example: "\" = "\\"). It will print out as a '\'.